# Why is my android app losing ability to read/write its own files?

Tags: android, file-permissions

I am having a strange problem. My app downloads reference files both to private files directory (data/data) and to public app specific directory (Android/data). The problem I am having is that when updating the app it will no longer read the download files and if I try to get the app to download them again it will not overwrite the old ones.

In one case I am using FileReader and BufferedReader to populate an ArrayList.
In another case I am using DocumentBuilderFactory to populate an ArrayList. In all cases files are downloaded using DownloadManager with some of them having post downloading processing done so that DocFactory will parse them correctly.
Biggest problem is I can't reproduce the issue consistently.

Comment: To increase the chances of helping you, please add the relevant code snippets to the question.

Comment: A piece of code could help us.......Do you use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream and FileOutputStream to create/read those files?